# python nested import alias

Tags: python, import, module

I want to do the following in python where XYZ, _a and _d are packages and foo() is defined inside _d:

```
XYZ._a._d.foo()
```

However I want to alias _a to a and _d to d so that I can call it like:

```
a.d.foo()
```

I tried to do the following but it seems the aliasing does not take effect the way I expected and it says "No module named a". Is there a way to accomplish this?

```
from XYZ import _a as a
from a import _d as d

a.d.foo()
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the import aliases are defined in the current module and not inside the _d module, then you can't intuitively do that. The purpose of aliasing is to make easy for the current module to access the deep one.

```
from XYZ import _a as a
from XYZ._a import _d as d # sets d in the current module only

d.foo() #works
a._d.foo() #works
a.d.foo() #fails
```

if you want to change the `_a` namespace you must set it there directly

```
from XYZ import _a as a
from XYZ._a import _d as d
XYZ.a.d = d

a.d.foo() #works
```

tl;dr in other words

```
from XYZ import _a as a
```

is (almost) the same as

```
from XYZ import _a
a = _a
```

in that the alias only exists in the current module scope, the module doing the importing.